Product 'Short description' and 'Specification' not displaying in admin Magento 2.4.7
I am using magento 2.4.7. When i create new product in admin, everything work as expected. but when i try to edit product, in that case short description and specification field show blank, but i did check in database its its still there in "catalog_product_entity_text" table
Also when i try to edit these 2 field.. its not updating in database(still old data there) as well as not displaying in admin text editor.
Please help me on this issue.
